# Sorting a list with the .orderby

Tags: c#

Simple question really I just seem to be stuck here.

I am trying to split a string in a list and order by the first "tidtilbage" %d and &h, but as of right now this gives me the last bit of the string, so the name and not the time-left, and iIwant to sort it by the first bit.

How can I reverse this action?

```
string lines = tidtilbage.ToString("%d") + " dag(e)" + " " 
             + tidtilbage.ToString("%h") + " time(r)" + " - " 
             + p.SamAccountName.ToUpper() + " - " + p.DisplayName + "\n\n";

list_sorted.Add(lines.ToString());
string[] Separator = new string[] { "time(r)" };
list_sorted = list_sorted.OrderBy(s => s.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]).ToList();
```

When i try chaging the index to 0 instead of 1 iam still not getting the disired sorting. i get:

0 dag(e) 20 time(r) - xx - xx

1 dag(e) 3 time(r) - xx - xx

13 dag(e) 22 time(r) - xx - xx

3 dag(e) 23 time(r) - xx - xx

5 dag(e) 21 time(r) - xx - xx

5 dag(e) 21 time(r)- xx - xx

6 dag(e) 2 time(r) - xx - xx

9 dag(e) 1 time(r) - xx - xx

9 dag(e) 21 time(r) - xx - xx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because C# collections are **zero index based**.
In other words, `collection[1]` is the second item or the collection. If you want to sort it by the first item, you need to use `[0]`.

You can simply change:

```
.OrderBy(s => s.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[1])
```

to

```
.OrderBy(s => s.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[0])
```

At the same time, your code has some other issues:

1. You do not need to apply `.ToString()` to an item which is string already:

   ```
   list_sorted.Add(lines.ToString()); // incorrect
   list_sorted.Add(lines); // correct
   ```
2. You can utilize `string.Format` or C# 6.0 string interpolation instead of `+` concatenation.

   Hardly readable and maintainable:

   ```
   string lines = tidtilbage.ToString("%d") + " dag(e)" + " " 
                + tidtilbage.ToString("%h") + " time(r)" + " - " 
                + p.SamAccountName.ToUpper() + " - " + p.DisplayName + "\n\n";
   ```

   Now looks better:

   ```
   string lines = String.Format("{0:D} dag(e) {0:H} time(r) - {1} - {2}\n\n", 
       tidlitbage, p.SamAccountName.ToUpper(), p.DisplayName);
   ```

   or even

   ```
   string lines = $"{tidlitbage:D} dag(e) {tidlitbage:H} time(r) - {p.SamAccountName.ToUpper()} - {p.DisplayName}\n\n");
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer @Yeldarkurmangaliyev! I am still not getting the desired sorting. ive edited my quetions so you can see what i mean. :-) i want the lowest => highest

Comment: @MathiasRønnowNørtoft Since you sort strings, C# sorts them in lexicographical order. You need to sort your `tidtilbage` collection first (I guess, it is a `DateTime`), and then convert them to a string `List`.

Comment: Thanks again, i will try that! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're taking the second position of split return.

```
 list_sorted = list_sorted.OrderBy(s => s.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]).ToList();
```

Try change the [1] for [0].

```
list_sorted = list_sorted.OrderBy(s => s.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]).ToList();
```

Or use .First(), (with .Last() you cant take de last one), or .elementAt(X) is useful too.

Answer (score 1):

if im not understanding ur question wrongly, then what you want must be array [0] rather than [1]. After you `split` ur String, the first array would be placed into array [0] rather than [1].

```
list_sorted = list_sorted.OrderBy(s => s.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]).ToList();
```